# Django issue playing audio files

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am using Javascript in a Django project to make an audio player/visualiser but I am having a problem getting the audio to play when the link is clicked. Having tested a few small functions in app.js I can see it is working in the HTML file but for some reason when I try to play the audio it says no supported source found and that my audio file was not found. The Javascript works fine in another project but I cannot get it to work within Django. I am new to Django so any help would be brilliant, thanks.

```
export default class AudioPlayer {
constructor(selector = '.audioPlayer', audio = []) {
    this.playerElement = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.audio = audio;
    this.currentAudio = null;
    this.createPlayerElements();
    this.audioContext = null;
}

createVisualiser() {
    this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const src = this.audioContext.createMediaElementSource(this.audioElement);
    const analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
    const canvas = this.visualiserElement;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    src.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
    analyser.fftSize = 128;
    const bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    const dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
    const barWidth = (canvas.width / bufferLength) * 2.5;
    let barHeight;
    let bar;

    function renderFrame() {
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
        bar = 0;
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
            barHeight = dataArray[i] - 100;
            const r = barHeight + (50 * (i / bufferLength));
            ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${r}, 100, 50)`;
            ctx.fillRect(bar, canvas.height - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
            bar += barWidth + 2;
        }
    }

    renderFrame();

}

createPlayerElements() {
    this.audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    this.audioElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    const playlistElement = document.createElement('div');
    playlistElement.classList.add('playlist');
    this.visualiserElement = document.createElement('canvas');

    this.playerElement.appendChild(this.audioElement);
    this.playerElement.appendChild(playlistElement);
    this.playerElement.appendChild(this.visualiserElement);
    this.createPlaylistElement(playlistElement);
}

createPlaylistElement(playlistElement) {
    this.audio.forEach(audio => {
        const audioItem = document.createElement('a');
        audioItem.classList.add('musicA');
        audioItem.href = audio.url;
        audioItem.innerHTML = `<i class="fa fa-play"></i>${audio.name}`;
        this.setupEventListener(audioItem);
        playlistElement.appendChild(audioItem);
    });
}

setupEventListener(audioItem) {
    audioItem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!this.audioContext) {
            this.createVisualiser();
        }

        const isCurrentAudio = audioItem.getAttribute('href') == (this.currentAudio && this.currentAudio.getAttribute('href'));

        if (isCurrentAudio && !this.audioElement.paused) {
            this.setPlayIcon(this.currentAudio);
            this.audioElement.pause();
            console.log('paused');
        }
        else if (isCurrentAudio && this.audioElement.paused) {
            this.setPuaseIcon(this.currentAudio);
            this.audioElement.play();
        }
        else {
            if (this.currentAudio) {
                this.setPlayIcon(this.currentAudio);
            }
            this.currentAudio = audioItem;
            this.setPuaseIcon(this.currentAudio);
            this.audioElement.src = this.currentAudio.getAttribute('href');
            this.audioElement.play();
        }
    });
}

setPlayIcon(element) {
    const icon = element.querySelector('i');
    icon.classList.remove('fa-pause');
    icon.classList.add('fa-play');
}

setPuaseIcon(element) {
    const icon = element.querySelector('i');
    icon.classList.remove('fa-play');
    icon.classList.add('fa-pause');
}


}
```

I have then created a new AudioPlayer in my app.js:

```
import AudioPlayer from './AudioPlayer.js';

const audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer('.audioPlayer', [
    { url: "musicPlayer/static/songs/song1.mp3", name: "abc" },
]);
```

The musicPlayer.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home")
]
```

And the project .urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('musicPlayer.urls')),
]
```

The musicPlayer file:

```
musicPlayer
|
|-__pycache__
|-migrations
|-static
|   |
|   |-css
|   |
|   |-javascript
|   |    |
|   |    |-app.js
|   |    |-AudioPlayer.js
|   |-songs
|-templates
|-urls.py
|-views.py
| ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure because I can't see your project structure, but is the audioPlayer urls inside of the musicPlayers app? or no?

it looks like you haven't included the audioPlayer urls anywhere...They're not in the musicPlayers.urls or the project urls, so effectively, you are trying to go to a url that they project can't find, because you haven't imported it properly.

You either need to import the audioPlayer.urls into the musicPlayer urls if the audioPlayer is in that app, or, if it's it's own app, then it needs to be imported into the project urls.

hopefully that's solve the 404, you might also have to make a view, and then connect the view to the url. I'm not entirely sure how the pure js functions work with urls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the AudioPlayer is a Javascript file in the musicPlayer folder so I'm not sure how I can do this.

Comment: You could, maybe should, import the js file into a template, and then make a view in mediaPlayer/views.py (that calls the template you made) that you then register in the musicPlay/urls.py. and then in that template the js can be called for the audioPlayer functions, within the html like normal js? does that make sense?

Comment: I think that is what I have done, I have a home.html which extends a base.html where I have a script with the type='module' and src='/static/javascript/app.js'. Then I have a view called home which calls my home template. Having tested a few small functions in app.js I can see it is working in the HTML file but for some reason when I try to play the audio it says no supported source found and my audio file was not found.

Comment: So that sounds like maybe a javascript error, and not a django error, if the script is being loaded and working. have you checked the path to your mp3 file, and googled what "no supported source" means? maybe it's not picking up your speakers or something